# Handling escaped url while processing RESTful requests

Tags: spring, api, rest, tomcat, jersey

Using
1. tomcat
2. spring jersey integration

One of the uri fragments in the path contains a '/' and i correctly escape it by replacing it with %2f. However the request never lands up correctly at my request processor.

Example URI

/persons/bad_person_identifier%2fabcd

the unique identifier of a person might be 'bad_person_identifier/abcd'

Comment: This approach works in jersey grizzly server but not in tomcat

Comment: Escaped where? The URL in your browser or in your Java server code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with tomcat 6.x

Solution:
Is to set system property for starting tmcat
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH: true

Issue details:

Fixed in Apache Tomcat 6.0.10

Important: Directory traversal CVE-2007-0450

Tomcat permits '\', '%2F' and '%5C' as path delimiters. When Tomcat is used behind a proxy (including, but not limited to, Apache HTTP server with mod_proxy and mod_jk) configured to only proxy some contexts, a HTTP request containing strings like "/../" may allow attackers to work around the context restriction of the proxy, and access the non-proxied contexts.

The following Java system properties have been added to Tomcat to provide additional control of the handling of path delimiters in URLs (both options default to false):

org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH: true|false
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH: true|false
Due to the impossibility to guarantee that all URLs are handled by Tomcat as they are in proxy servers, Tomcat should always be secured as if no proxy restricting context access was used.

Affects: 6.0.0-6.0.9

Answer (score 0):

The correct identifier for / is `%2f`

Comment: Ok i missed the 'f'. That was a typo in the question. Have corrected the question now.